# Oracle left join rules

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, left-join

I have a question, and maybe my search skills are lacking so please feel free to close this and point me to a duplicate of my question.

How does Oracle 11g resolve ambiguous left join? By ambiguous I mean suppose a left join matches two rows on the joined in table to a single row on the source table. Which row will get joined in? Is it deterministic at all? If so, what are the ambiguity resolution rules?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure what you're getting at... a left join will return ALL matching rows in the "left" table, and ANY matching rows in the "right" table. If there's no matching rows in the right table. those particular fields in the result set are nulled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a join condition matches multiple rows, regardless of it being an inner or outer join, all those rows will be present in the result set. For a left (outer) join, if no matches are found, then its fields will be null.

Answer (score 2):

There's no ambiguity. Basically, rows get duplicated as necessary:

```
create table a(
  a_id number,
  a_name varchar2(10)
);

create table b(
  b_id number,
  b_name varchar2(10)
);

insert into a (a_id, a_name) values (1, 'A');
insert into a (a_id, a_name) values (2, 'B');
insert into a (a_id, a_name) values (3, 'C');

insert into b (b_id, b_name) values (1, 'X');
insert into b (b_id, b_name) values (1, 'Y');
insert into b (b_id, b_name) values (2, 'Z');

select *
from a
left join b on a.a_id=b.b_id
order by a.a_id, a.a_name, b.b_id, b.b_name
```

```
A_ID   A_NAME B_ID   B_NAME
1      A      1      X
1      A      1      Y
2      B      2      Z
3      C      (null) (null)
```

You can think of left joins as general cross joins with filters.

Comment: +1 for "There's no ambiguity"